# Add Change Item order ribbon in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, ribbon

I want to add Change item order ribbon into ribbon panel. I have created feature and activated, however i still cant see the item order ribbon. Can anyone help me with this?
below is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <!--Change Item order Ribbon-->
  <CustomAction
    Id="SPChangeItemOrder"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.ListItem"
    RegistrationId="101"
    RegistrationType="List"
    Title="List View Ribbon Customization"
    >
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.Controls._children">
          <!--Get Details from CMDUI.XML-->
          <Button 
            Id="Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.ChangeItemOrder"
            Alt="Change the order of the items in this list."
            Sequence="20"
            Command="ChangeLinkOrder"
            LabelText="$Resources:core,cui_ButChangeItemOrder;"
            ToolTipTitle="$Resources:core,cui_ButChangeItemOrder;"
            ToolTipDescription="$Resources:core,cui_STT_ButChangeItemOrder;"
            TemplateAlias="o2"
            Image16by16="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap16x16.png" Image16by16Top="-192" Image16by16Left="-144"
            Image32by32="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap32x32.png" Image32by32Top="-192" Image32by32Left="-288"
              />

        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>

      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler Command="ChangeLinkOrder" CommandAction="javascript:alert('Please check Change Item Order');"></CommandUIHandler>
      </CommandUIHandlers>

    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this where RegistrationID is the Type value of a list definition.  You don't need the CommandUIHandler if you want to use SharePoint's OOB Change Item Order command.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">

  <!--Change Item order Ribbon-->
  <CustomAction
    Id="XYZ.Webpart.Links.XYZLinksListDefinition.RibbonSortOrderButton"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
    RegistrationId="30099"
    RegistrationType="List"
    Title="List View Ribbon Customization" >
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.Controls._children">
          <Button
            Id="Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.RibbonSortOrderButton"
            Sequence="25"
            Command="ChangeLinkOrder"
            Image16by16="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap16x16.png" Image16by16Top="-192" Image16by16Left="-144"
            Image32by32="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap32x32.png" Image32by32Top="-192" Image32by32Left="-288"
            LabelText="$Resources:core,cui_ButChangeItemOrder;"
            ToolTipTitle="$Resources:core,cui_ButChangeItemOrder;"
            ToolTipDescription="$Resources:core,cui_STT_ButChangeItemOrder;"
            TemplateAlias="o1" />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 0):

Invalid value for attribute location in customaction element, choose right location value from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802730.aspx